# Group a list of object by nested object parameters

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of TestA objects

```
TestA {
   int a;
   int b;
   TestC;
}

TestC {
  int d;
  String e;
  String f;

}
```

I want to group list of TestA by the combination of `e, f` variables of `TestC`..I am trying to use `java stream api`.But unable to figure out a possible solution.Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Example:

```
TestA x1 = new TestA(); x1.setTestC(new TestC(d1, e1, f1));
TestA x2 = new TestA(); x2.setTestC(new TestC(d1, e1, f1));
TestA x3 = new TestA(); x3.setTestC(new TestC(d2, e2, f2));

List<TestA> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add(x1);
l1.add(x2);
l1.add(x3);
```

I want a new map which is grouped by combination of e, f of TestC like below:
`Map<String, List<TestA>>`
where key will be combination of `e, f(like string combination of e, f)` with List grouped based on that..example format below

```
Map<"e+f", List<TestA>>
```

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. Please add more details

Comment: Hello could you clarify what do you mean by "combination of `e, f` variables"? Maybe modifying your example to something like `Person{ int age, int height, Address address}` `Address{ int houseNumber, String street, String city}` would help.

Comment: Your result should have a map where key is a `String` according to your example. But the grouping has to be taken as the combination. How do you expect to form that key? Just concatenation?

Comment: i want key as concatenation of `e+f`

Comment: In `List<TestA> l1` you will have multiple `TestA` with different `TestC` object in it. (In your case `x1, x2, x3` has different `TestC` objects), from this multiple `TestC` objects which `e+f` you take for key?

Comment: Looks like candidate for `Collectors.groupingBy`. Something like `Map<String, List<TestA>> collect = l1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ta -> ta.getTestC().getE() + ta.getTestC().getF()));`

Comment: @PshemoI  I already tried `l1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ta -> ta.getTestC().getE() + ta.getTestC().getF()));` but it is throwing error..I could not figure out a way to put it correctly in grouping by function

Comment: got  the solution.the issue was there was issue with my data `l1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ta -> ta.getTestC().getE() + ta.getTestC().getF()));` is working..but some values were null which was throwing error..filtered the null values in the stream and it worked..

Comment: @user2755407 There shouldn't be `l` at the end of my *nick* `@Pshemo`. Since you used `@Pshemol` I was not notified about your comment - good thing I didn't close this tab yet or I would miss your replay. Anyway "*but some values were null which was throwing error..filtered the null values in the stream and it worked..*" doesn't help me help you since I don't know what you tried, nor what error you are facing. But `filter` *is* correct tool for that task (assuming you don't want to include elements with `null` values).

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks! Apologies for adding  `l` at the end of your username

Comment: No problem, but I still don't know problem you are facing. Anyway if you want to skip some element with null value at some point you may use something like `.filter(t->Objects.nonNull(t.getTestC()))` if TestA may have `null` instead of TestC and you want to avoid it. After/Instead of that you can use `.filter(t->Objects.nonNull(t.getTestC.f()))` to avoid TestA in which TestC the `f` field holds `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Using records in lieu of classes (for ease) and some sample data, here is what I came up with. This simply streams the lists and groups based on the two concatenated strings in the `TestA` class as per your example.

```
record TestA(int getA, int getB, TestC getTestC) {
    public String toString() {
        return "[" +getA + ", " + getB + ", " + getTestC + "]";
    }
}

record TestC(int getD, String getE, String getF) {
    public String toString() {
        return "TestC(" + getD + ", " + getE + ", " + getF;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

int d1 = 1;
int d2 = 2;
String e1 = "C";
String e2 = "R";
String f2 = "G";
String f1 = "Z";
TestA x1 = new TestA(1, 2, new TestC(d1, e1, f1));
TestA x2 = new TestA(1, 2, new TestC(d1, e1, f1));
TestA x3 = new TestA(1, 2, new TestC(d2, e2, f2));

List<TestA> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
l1.add(x1);
l1.add(x2);
l1.add(x3);

Map<String, List<TestA>> result = l1.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t.getTestC().getE() + t.getTestC().getF()));
result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
RG=[[1, 2, TestC(2, R, G]]
CZ=[[1, 2, TestC(1, C, Z], [1, 2, TestC(1, C, Z]]
```